# How to calculate a special metric from two dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

I have a dictionary with films and values called `a`:

```
a = {'Star Wars (1977)': 484, 
'Return of the Jedi (1983)': 422, 
'Contact (1997)': 402, 
'Fargo (1996)': 395, 
'Liar Liar (1997)': 394, 
'Scream (1996)': 391, 
'English Patient, The (1996)': 388, 
'Toy Story (1995)': 383, 
'Independence Day (ID4) (1996)': 353, 
'Air Force One (1997)': 352}
```

And another one called `b`:

```
b = [(5.000000000000001, 'Star Wars (1977)'), 
(5.000000000000001, 'Return of the Jedi (1983)'), 
(5.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'), 
(5.0, 'Air Force One (1997)'), 
(5.0, 'Liar Liar (1997)')]
```

I want for first three films from `b` calculate according value from dictionary `a` divided by sum of all values from that dictionary. I need a function which will do that. So value for 'Star Wars (1977)' will be 484 divided by 484 + 422 + 402 + ...+ 352. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using sum on a.values() to get the total then divide any given `a[key] / total`:

```
a = {'Star Wars (1977)': 484,
     'Return of the Jedi (1983)': 422,
     'Contact (1997)': 402,
     'Fargo (1996)': 395,
     'Liar Liar (1997)': 394,
     'Scream (1996)': 391,
     'English Patient, The (1996)': 388,
     'Toy Story (1995)': 383,
     'Independence Day (ID4) (1996)': 353,
     'Air Force One (1997)': 352}

# Get Total From A
total = sum(a.values())

b = [(5.000000000000001, 'Star Wars (1977)'),
     (5.000000000000001, 'Return of the Jedi (1983)'),
     (5.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
     (5.0, 'Air Force One (1997)'),
     (5.0, 'Liar Liar (1997)')]

# For First 3 Films in B
for v, m in b[:3]:
    # Divide a[m] by total
    print(f'{m}: {a[m] / total}')
```

```
Star Wars (1977): 0.12209889001009082
Return of the Jedi (1983): 0.10645812310797174
Toy Story (1995): 0.09661957618567103
```

---

As a function:

```
def func(movies, d):
    total = sum(d.values())
    return [(d[movie] / total, movie) for movie in movies]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = {'Star Wars (1977)': 484,
         'Return of the Jedi (1983)': 422,
         'Contact (1997)': 402,
         'Fargo (1996)': 395,
         'Liar Liar (1997)': 394,
         'Scream (1996)': 391,
         'English Patient, The (1996)': 388,
         'Toy Story (1995)': 383,
         'Independence Day (ID4) (1996)': 353,
         'Air Force One (1997)': 352}
    b = [(5.000000000000001, 'Star Wars (1977)'),
         (5.000000000000001, 'Return of the Jedi (1983)'),
         (5.0, 'Toy Story (1995)'),
         (5.0, 'Air Force One (1997)'),
         (5.0, 'Liar Liar (1997)')]

    print(func([v for _, v in b[:3]], a))
```

```
[(0.12209889001009082, 'Star Wars (1977)'),
 (0.10645812310797174, 'Return of the Jedi (1983)'),
 (0.09661957618567103, 'Toy Story (1995)')]
```